# How to delete a particular line in huge XML file without opening it.

Tags: xml, unix

I have Huge XML file (around 4Gb) and I know that lines from 3-5 are creating some trouble while parsing them,so I just want to remove them.

I have tried using this with some other small xml file

> sed '3,5d' filename.xml

but the change is not done to the file instead its showing the changed content of the file on terminal.

Any Other Suggestion?

Comment: `man sed`: _-i edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)_

Comment: Use streamreader and streamwriter.   Read and write 2 lines.  Read 3 lines and do not write.  Then read and write rest of file.  With huge xml files you must use a XmlReader, but in this case streamreader and streamwriter will work.